# Toggle between network and GPS provider on service not on activity

Tags: android, service, gps, locationlistener

I want to track user location continuously as a background service in android, i am able to achieve it using background services and broadcast reciever but not able to figure out how to toggle between network and gps provider depending upon availability.

**backgroundService.java**

```
 @Override

        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        mylistner = new NewLocationListener(getBaseContext());

        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);

        criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
        LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) getBaseContext()
        .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        String bestProvider = locManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Best Provider "+bestProvider, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        locManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 1000, 5, mylistner);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Successfully Called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

Initially bestProvider will have either gps or network but what if it's gps initially and then if user turns off gps, it should give me coordinate using network. Again, if user switches on gps then location provider should be from gps.

On service there are onProviderEnabled and onProviderDisabled method how to use them for the purpose

as given as a solution in many similar question in stack overflow i don't want to send both network and gps provider from beginning i want to switch as per the availabilty.
is it achievable in service.
Thanks in advance